# What exception to throw when dataset is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, dataset

I am working on C# (ASP.NET). I am retrieving records from Database and storing results in DataSet. I would like to throw exception if my retrieve dataSet is null or empty. What Exception should I throw?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can create custom exceptions that can specifiy specifically what went wrong for you.

Comment: How are you filling your `DataSet`, if you are using `DataAdapter.Fill` then I don't think you can get `null` back in the dataset.

Comment: [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx) might be appropriate... Otherwise probably a custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `Exception` to thrown like this:

```
 public class DatabaseConnectionException : ApplicationException
    {
        public DatabaseConnectionException () { }

        public DatabaseConnectionException (string message)
            : base(message) { }

        public DatabaseConnectionException (string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can throw [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if(dataSet == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException("The datasource cannot be null");
```

It is better to create your custom business exception and provide meaningful error message

```
public class BusinessException:ApplicationException
{
//
}

if(dataSet == null)
   throw new BusinessException("The datasource cannot be null");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom exception like

```
var dataSet = //your dataSet;

if(dataSet == null)
   throw new MyException
```